# Can I use a HBA to connect to Internet

Tags: cisco, nic, fibre-channel, hba, qlogic

I recently got a QLogic QLE2460 network card which seems to be a Host Bus Adapter. Can I somehow use it as a network interface (NIC) between my server/workstation and a Cisco Catalyst switch with fibre channel modules.

If no, what fibre channel card would be proper for that purpose?

Comment: You got it, but you are unsure of the use ? You might be better to ask the vendor

Comment: I got it with $15 because it was sold as a network card. I'm just starting with fibre optics and didn't know that there are network cards - and - network cards. The coppers I've been using before are all NICs. And I asked it because some of the geeks on this forum might know a work-around.

Comment: Ask for your money back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot use the QLogic QLE2460 to connect to the Internet**

This is a Fiber Channel HBA and is not a network card.

The 2400 Series of QLogic Fiber Channal HBA's connect storage to hosts via Fiber Channel.  This series of HBA is older and can only achieve 4Gps of transfer rate.

These cards do not get an IP address.

Comment: You can actually configure IP over FC - I've done it, once, very niche requirement, either way the dude's been ripped off/lied to